# $ is not a function error on Drupal

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, counter

My code works fine in the local environment but not on the website. I dont understand what I'm missing here.

Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  'use strict';
  //============================== COUNTER-UP =========================
  $('.counter').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 2000
  });
});
```

Error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js?p4xosk:4)
    at fire (jquery.js?v=1.10.2:3048)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?v=1.10.2:3160)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?v=1.10.2:433)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery.js?v=1.10.2:104)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to define $ :

```
(function($){
 $(document).ready(function(){
  'use strict';
  //============================== COUNTER-UP =========================
  $('.counter').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 2000
  });
 });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: In Bootstrap they are wrapping like  so:

```+function ($) {
  'use strict';


$(document).ready(function(){
  //============================== COUNTER-UP =========================
  $('.counter').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 2000
  });
 });
})}(jQuery);```

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal $ does not default to jQuery.
As best practice you should not assign it yourself as well.
Just use "jQuery" instead of "$" in your code, e.g. replace `$('.counter')` with `jQuery('.counter')`

Comment: Markus you are talking nonsense. Look at [link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview). Drupal don't need `$(document).ready()`, you have to add instead `(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
     $('input.myCustomBehavior', context).once('myCustomBehavior', function () {
      // Apply the myCustomBehaviour effect to the elements only once.
    });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);` to your js file like in example