# Drupal 10 JQuery TypeErrors: "x" is not a function \ "x" is not a constructor

Tags: jquery, typeerror, drupal-10

On Drupal-8 this JS code (2 JS code\files of module) works OK.
I have errors on Drupal-10 with the same code\module.

1. (line.80) Uncaught TypeError: base is not a constructor jquery.ui.widget.js:80:18 https://playcode.io/1739162
2. (line.279) Uncaught TypeError: blockbuilder_admin.sortable is not a function admin.js:279:24 https://playcode.io/1739170

jquery.ui.widget.js

```
    });

    basePrototype = new base();
    // we need to make the options hash a property directly on the new instance
    // otherwise we'll modify the options hash on the prototype that we're
    // inheriting from
```

admin.js

```
    if( ! blockbuilder_admin.length ) return false; 
    
    blockbuilder_admin.sortable({ 
      start: function(e, ui){
           ui.placeholder.width(ui.item.find('.gavias-blockbuilder-content').first().width() - 20);
           ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height() - 20);
```

Does anyone greet what to correct?

- https://www.drupal.org/node/3158256
- https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_collapsible/issues/3380762
- [$ is not a function error on Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060058/is-not-a-function-error-on-drupal)